# Ayuda con SVG. Ajustar tamaños

Tags: css3, svg

Estoy haciendo cambios en mi web y me dieron unos íconos, que para realizar animaciones pequeñas las he exportado como svg, pero al momento de ponerlos en la web, sólo 2 mantienen el tamaño correcto:

```css
/*Inicio barra header.*/

#menu_opaco {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #39404A;
  height: 10vh;
  position: absolute;
}

#contenedor_logos {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  top: 50%;
}


/*Final barra header.*/


/*Inicio contenedor de logos.*/

.contenedor_otros {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 32%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.contenedor_otros a {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#logo_sena,
#logo_grupo,
#logo_sennova {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 60%;
}

#logo_sennova {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}

.contenedor_otros a .enlaces_logos {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.reiniciar_pagina {
  max-width: 20%;
}

#isologo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 1%;
  max-width: 7%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}


/*Inicio contenedor de logos.*/


/*Inicio contenedor de botones y manual del header.*/

.botones_header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  right: 2%;
  width: 25%;
}

.opcionHeader,
.opcionHeader a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s all;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.opcionHeader a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.opcionHeader .iconoOpcion svg {
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  transition: .5s all;
}

.opcionHeader:hover .iconoOpcion svg,
.opcionHeader:hover .nombreOpcion {
  stroke: #FF6B00;
  color: #FF6B00;
  transition: .5s all;
}

.opcionHeader .iconoOpcion {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  transition: .5s all;
}


/*Final contenedor de botones y manual del header.*/


/*Final contenedor del header.*/
```

```html
<!--Inicio cabecera de la página.-->
<header>

  <div id="menu_opaco"></div>
  <!--Barra opaca que contiene los links de logos.-->

  <div id="contenedor_logos">

    <a href="" class="reiniciar_pagina"><img src="" class="enlaces_logos" id="isologo"></a>

    <div class="contenedor_otros">

      <a href=""><img src="" alt="" class="enlaces_logos" id="logo_sena"></a>

      <a href=""><img src="" alt="" id="logo_grupo"></a>

      <a href=""><img src="" alt="" class="enlaces_logos" id="logo_sennova"></a>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="botones_header">

    <div class="opcionHeader inicioSesion">

      <div class="iconoOpcion">

        <svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 468.13 433.29"><defs><style>.cls-1,.cls-2{fill:none; stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px;}.cls-2{stroke-linecap:round;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M18.42,317.18c-6.67,12.45-.37,28.82,14.07,36.55s31.56,3.91,38.23-8.54Z" transform="translate(-6.87 -4.58)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M460.74,317.18c6.67,12.45.37,28.82-14.07,36.55s-31.56,3.91-38.23-8.54Z" transform="translate(-6.87 -4.58)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M328.5,215.54l84.67,146.64c18.13,31.42-4.54,70.69-40.81,70.69H106.24c-36.27,0-58.94-39.27-40.8-70.69l83.61-144.82a40,40,0,0,1,34.31-20,173.36,173.36,0,0,0,64.12,8.56A172.5,172.5,0,0,0,295,196.4C298.44,196.37,306.16,196.77,328.5,215.54Z" transform="translate(-6.87 -4.58)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="234.06" cy="90.08" r="85.08"/><path class="cls-2" d="M142.77,219s-130.9,52.35-130.9,78.53S77.32,341.6,77.32,341.6" transform="translate(-6.87 -4.58)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M339.11,219S470,271.36,470,297.54s-65.45,44.06-65.45,44.06" transform="translate(-6.87 -4.58)"/></svg>

      </div>

      <div class="nombreOpcion">Iniciar Sesión</div>

    </div>

    <div class="opcionHeader">

      <a href="registro/">

        <div class="iconoOpcion">

          <svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 481.41 435.61"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M133.34,25A78.84,78.84,0,1,0,25.63,140.19Z" transform="translate(-0.14 -3.26)"/><rect class="cls-1" x="37.55" y="91.11" width="151.38" height="50.46" rx="0.94" transform="translate(-49.22 116.32) rotate(-46.92)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M172.72,108.83H321a1.57,1.57,0,0,1,1.57,1.57V373.74a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H171.15a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V110.4a1.57,1.57,0,0,1,1.57-1.57Z" transform="translate(-98.13 253.5) rotate(-46.92)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M418.92,302.89,318.63,410.14a1,1,0,0,0,.56,1.64L479.9,438.36A1,1,0,0,0,481,437L420.54,303.16A1,1,0,0,0,418.92,302.89Z" transform="translate(-0.14 -3.26)"/></svg>

        </div>

        <div class="nombreOpcion">Registrarse</div>

      </a>

    </div>

    <div class="opcionHeader">

      <div class="iconoOpcion">

        <svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 477.52 442.81"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M377.78,322.58a98.22,98.22,0,1,0,0-196.44Z" transform="translate(-3.48 -2.96)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M63.49,173.28a55,55,0,1,0,0,110Z" transform="translate(-3.48 -2.96)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M326.45,331.45,150.4,433.1c-37.72,21.77-84.86-5.45-84.86-49V64.61c0-43.55,47.14-70.77,84.86-49L324.27,116a48.07,48.07,0,0,1,24,41.2l1.14,134.06A46,46,0,0,1,326.45,331.45Z" transform="translate(-3.48 -2.96)"/></svg>

      </div>

      <div class="nombreOpcion">Activar Voz</div>

    </div>

    <div class="opcionHeader">

      <a href="documentos/manual_valtec.pdf" download="Manual ValTec.pdf">

        <div class="iconoOpcion">

          <svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 287.52 366.31"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M252.49,371.61H64A44.51,44.51,0,0,1,19.48,327.1V60.91A44.52,44.52,0,0,1,64,16.39H198.65l-1.56,88.81C230.4,71.9,297,82.11,297,82.11v245A44.51,44.51,0,0,1,252.49,371.61Z" transform="translate(-14.48 -10.31)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M297,83s0-77.71-133.21-66.61" transform="translate(-14.48 -10.31)"/><line class="cls-1" x1="53.1" y1="150.39" x2="230.71" y2="150.39"/><line class="cls-1" x1="53.1" y1="194.8" x2="230.71" y2="194.8"/><line class="cls-1" x1="53.1" y1="250.3" x2="230.71" y2="250.3"/></svg>

        </div>

        <div class="nombreOpcion">Descargar Manual</div>

      </a>

    </div>

  </div>

</header>
<!--Final cabecera de la página.-->
```

Por favor, si alguien pudiera ayudarme sólo a ajustar los tamaños, lo agradecería.

Comment: Ya probaste insertar los svg en una etiqueta `img` y desde CSS tratar de modificarla?

Answer (score 1):

Varias cosas:

1. Tienes el mismo `id ="Capa_1"`  repetido 4 veces. Ya que no los necesitas en este ejemplo los he borrado. Si creas que los necesitas por favor utiliza algo como: `Capa_1`, `Capa_2`... etc
2. Tienes un contenedor flex cuyos ítems no tienen una anchura. Para areglarlo he añadido `.opcionHeader{flex:0 0 25%;}`
3. Lo importante: Para arreglar lo del tamaño tienes que utilizar elementos svg cuyo `viewBox` tiene la misma razón de aspecto (aspect ratio). He optado por crear unos elementos svg cuadrados.

Por ejemplo en el caso del último elemento svg tu tienes `viewBox="0 0 287.52 366.31"` lo que te da un elemento svg más alto (366.31) que ancho (287.52). Para transformarlo en un cuadrado podrías utilizar `viewBox="0 0 366.31 366.31"`. Sin embargo en este caso la imagen aparecería a la izquierda. Para centrarlo he modificado el componente `x` del `viewBox` así que ahora utilizo `viewBox="-42 0 370 370"`

Observación: He añadido un `outline` a los elementos svg para que los pueda ver claramente. Puedes borrarlo.

```css
/*Inicio barra header.*/
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
svg{outline:1px solid white;}

#menu_opaco {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #39404A;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

#contenedor_logos {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  top: 50%;
}


/*Final barra header.*/


/*Inicio contenedor de logos.*/

.contenedor_otros {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 32%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.contenedor_otros a {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#logo_sena,
#logo_grupo,
#logo_sennova {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 60%;
}

#logo_sennova {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}

.contenedor_otros a .enlaces_logos {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.reiniciar_pagina {
  max-width: 20%;
}

#isologo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 1%;
  max-width: 7%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}


/*Inicio contenedor de logos.*/


/*Inicio contenedor de botones y manual del header.*/

.botones_header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  right: 2%;
  /*width: 25%;*/
}

.opcionHeader{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s all;
  margin:0;padding:0;
  flex:0 0 25%;
}

.opcionHeader a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.opcionHeader .iconoOpcion svg {
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  transition: .5s all;
}

.opcionHeader:hover .iconoOpcion svg,
.opcionHeader:hover .nombreOpcion {
  stroke: #FF6B00;
  color: #FF6B00;
  transition: .5s all;
}

.opcionHeader .iconoOpcion {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  transition: .5s all;
}


/*Final contenedor de botones y manual del header.*/


/*Final contenedor del header.*/
```

```html
<!--Inicio cabecera de la página.-->
<header>

  <div id="menu_opaco"></div>
  <!--Barra opaca que contiene los links de logos.-->

  <div id="contenedor_logos">

    <a href="" class="reiniciar_pagina"><img src="" class="enlaces_logos" id="isologo"></a>

    <div class="contenedor_otros">

      <a href=""><img src="" alt="" class="enlaces_logos" id="logo_sena"></a>

      <a href=""><img src="" alt="" id="logo_grupo"></a>

      <a href=""><img src="" alt="" class="enlaces_logos" id="logo_sennova"></a>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="botones_header">

    <div class="opcionHeader inicioSesion">

      <div class="iconoOpcion">

        <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -10 470 470"><defs><style>.cls-1,.cls-2{fill:none; stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px;}.cls-2{stroke-linecap:round;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M18.42,317.18c-6.67,12.45-.37,28.82,14.07,36.55s31.56,3.91,38.23-8.54Z" transform="translate(-6.87 -4.58)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M460.74,317.18c6.67,12.45.37,28.82-14.07,36.55s-31.56,3.91-38.23-8.54Z" transform="translate(-6.87 -4.58)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M328.5,215.54l84.67,146.64c18.13,31.42-4.54,70.69-40.81,70.69H106.24c-36.27,0-58.94-39.27-40.8-70.69l83.61-144.82a40,40,0,0,1,34.31-20,173.36,173.36,0,0,0,64.12,8.56A172.5,172.5,0,0,0,295,196.4C298.44,196.37,306.16,196.77,328.5,215.54Z" transform="translate(-6.87 -4.58)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="234.06" cy="90.08" r="85.08"/><path class="cls-2" d="M142.77,219s-130.9,52.35-130.9,78.53S77.32,341.6,77.32,341.6" transform="translate(-6.87 -4.58)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M339.11,219S470,271.36,470,297.54s-65.45,44.06-65.45,44.06" transform="translate(-6.87 -4.58)"/></svg>

      </div>

      <div class="nombreOpcion">Iniciar Sesión</div>

    </div>

    <div class="opcionHeader">

      <a href="registro/">

        <div class="iconoOpcion">

          <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -20 482 482"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M133.34,25A78.84,78.84,0,1,0,25.63,140.19Z" transform="translate(-0.14 -3.26)"/><rect class="cls-1" x="37.55" y="91.11" width="151.38" height="50.46" rx="0.94" transform="translate(-49.22 116.32) rotate(-46.92)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M172.72,108.83H321a1.57,1.57,0,0,1,1.57,1.57V373.74a0,0,0,0,1,0,0H171.15a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V110.4a1.57,1.57,0,0,1,1.57-1.57Z" transform="translate(-98.13 253.5) rotate(-46.92)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M418.92,302.89,318.63,410.14a1,1,0,0,0,.56,1.64L479.9,438.36A1,1,0,0,0,481,437L420.54,303.16A1,1,0,0,0,418.92,302.89Z" transform="translate(-0.14 -3.26)"/></svg>

        </div>

        <div class="nombreOpcion">Registrarse</div>

      </a>

    </div>

    <div class="opcionHeader">

      <div class="iconoOpcion">

        <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -20 480 480"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M377.78,322.58a98.22,98.22,0,1,0,0-196.44Z" transform="translate(-3.48 -2.96)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M63.49,173.28a55,55,0,1,0,0,110Z" transform="translate(-3.48 -2.96)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M326.45,331.45,150.4,433.1c-37.72,21.77-84.86-5.45-84.86-49V64.61c0-43.55,47.14-70.77,84.86-49L324.27,116a48.07,48.07,0,0,1,24,41.2l1.14,134.06A46,46,0,0,1,326.45,331.45Z" transform="translate(-3.48 -2.96)"/></svg>

      </div>

      <div class="nombreOpcion">Activar Voz</div>

    </div>

    <div class="opcionHeader">

      <a href="documentos/manual_valtec.pdf" download="Manual ValTec.pdf">

        <div class="iconoOpcion">

          <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-42 0 370 370"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M252.49,371.61H64A44.51,44.51,0,0,1,19.48,327.1V60.91A44.52,44.52,0,0,1,64,16.39H198.65l-1.56,88.81C230.4,71.9,297,82.11,297,82.11v245A44.51,44.51,0,0,1,252.49,371.61Z" transform="translate(-14.48 -10.31)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M297,83s0-77.71-133.21-66.61" transform="translate(-14.48 -10.31)"/><line class="cls-1" x1="53.1" y1="150.39" x2="230.71" y2="150.39"/><line class="cls-1" x1="53.1" y1="194.8" x2="230.71" y2="194.8"/><line class="cls-1" x1="53.1" y1="250.3" x2="230.71" y2="250.3"/></svg>

        </div>

        <div class="nombreOpcion">Descargar Manual</div>

      </a>

    </div>

  </div>

</header>
<!--Final cabecera de la página.-->
```